# scipy.linalg.cho_solve counterpart in R?

Tags: r, scipy

I was wondering if there is a counterpart to scipy.linalg.cho_solve in R. What the function does is given the cholesky factor L of A (A = LL') and b, it solves the original problem, Ax = b. (not Lx = b)

(So it is different from backsolve/forwardsolve)

Thank you,
Joon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realise this question is a little old, but I see that the answer

```
forwardsolve(L, forwardsolve(L, b), transp=TRUE)
```

hasn't been given yet. This uses the triangular structure, while keeping to the original question. This should be faster and more accurate for larger matrices. It might also be worth noting that `L <- t(chol(A))` since `chol` returns an upper triangular matrix.

```
A <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,5,5,1,5,14), nrow=3)
# Cholesky decomposition A = LL'
L <- t(chol(A))

# Make some b with known x
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
b <- A %*% x

# Solve
forwardsolve(L, forwardsolve(L, b), transp=TRUE)
```

Giving the answer:

```
> forwardsolve(L, forwardsolve(L, b), transp=TRUE)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a function doing that for you automatically, but given you have the cholesky factor L, it's easily done in one line by reconstructing the A matrix as defined by the decomposition A=LL' :

```
 A=matrix(c(1,1,1,1,5,5,1,5,14),nrow=3)
 # Cholesky decomposition A = LL'
 L <- chol(A)

 # Make some b with known x
 x <- c(1,2,3)
 b <- A%*%x

 # Solve
 solve( t(L) %*% L, b)
```

edit: be aware that in R, the definition of the Cholesky factor is related to A = L'L, which is why you have to put the transposed first in the solve.

edit2 : After reading Bates article, I realized it should be:

```
> solve(crossprod(L),b)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
```

Comment: Thanks. I was doing this (with tcrossprod) but I was wondering if there was more nicer way.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, then Doug Bates covered some of this in an [article](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf) he wrote for R News in 2004 (see page 18 of the linK).

The relevant bit is:

```
ch <- chol(crossprod(X))
chol.sol <- backsolve(ch, forwardsolve(ch, crossprod(X, y),
                                       upper = TRUE, trans = TRUE))
```

where `X` is the matrix of predictor variables.

Doug's article goes on to show how functionality in the Matrix package (which comes with R) can be used solve the same system very quickly indeed.

Comment: +1 for the link. Very interesting material, burried far too deep in the www. I am a bit surprised though about the complexity of the code you give here. I thought it could be done a bit shorter (see my answer). What did I miss?

Comment: Thanks. But if I'm not misunderstood, in this example you need X. I was looking for a way to do this without X.

Comment: @Joris Meys I think this thing will exploit the triangular structure of the cholesky factor, where just solving it does not.

Comment: @joon - ahh, OK, I see. I didn't grep that you *only* had L and b. Joris' answer would be the way to go.

Comment: @Joris - joon's comment is spot on about it exploiting the triangular structure. But it would appear I was solving the wrong question the smart way. You answered the right question the smart way! +1

Comment: I realise this question is a little old, but I see that the answer `forwardsolve(L, forwardsolve(L, b), transp=TRUE)` hasn't been given yet. This uses the triangular structure, while keeping to the original question. It might also be worth noting that `L <- t(chol(A))` since `chol` returns an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: @pete Thanks, useful, but perhaps stick that in an answer so your points get more exposure/don't get overlooked?

Comment: @Gavin didn't want to steal points since it's just a bugfix to your answer, but I see you have a couple more than me, so I'll go ahead and cut in line ;-)